# iOS 7 Sandbox Game Center Live Matches not matching on Cellular connection

Tags: ios7, game-center

Auto matching works fine on a wifi connection using

```
[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:matchRequest];
```

However, when I switch both devices to use the cellular data connection then the match won't get created.  It is just stuck looking for match "forever".  Any ideas on what would be causing that?  Is that as designed from Apple's matchmaking algorithm.